# Sorting elements with category not in reference list

Tags: xml, xslt

This is a follow-up to my previous question;
[Sorting on attribute collected from reference list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52254452/sorting-on-attribute-collected-from-reference-list)

Now I have added two VisitedCity elements, that are located in a part of the world not listed in the reference list used for sorting. I would like all such elements to end up at the end of the list sorted internally by the second (Date) key.

Here's the updated source xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Atlas>
    <Cities>
        <City id="1" worldPart="Africa">
            <Name>Luxor</Name>
            <Founded>-3200</Founded>
            <Location>Egypt</Location>
        </City>
        <City id="2" worldPart="Africa">
            <Name>Tripoli</Name>
            <Founded>-700</Founded>
            <Location>Libya</Location>
        </City>
        <City id="3" worldPart="Americas">
            <Name>Cholula</Name>
            <Founded>-200</Founded>
            <Location>Mexico</Location>
        </City>
        <City id="4" worldPart="Americas">
            <Name>Flores</Name>
            <Founded>-1000</Founded>
            <Location>Guatemala</Location>
        </City>
        <City id="5" worldPart="Europe">
            <Name>Argos</Name>
            <Founded>-5000</Founded>
            <Location>Greece</Location>
        </City>
        <City id="6" worldPart="Europe">
            <Name>Athens</Name>
            <Founded>-4000</Founded>
            <Location>Greece</Location>
        </City>
        <City id="7" worldPart="Asia">
            <Name>Varanasi</Name>
            <Founded>-1800</Founded>
            <Location>India</Location>
        </City>
        <City id="8" worldPart="Asia">
            <Name>Jakarta</Name>
            <Founded>397</Founded>
            <Location>Indonesia</Location>
        </City>
    </Cities>
    <VisitedCities lastUpdate="2018-09-10">
        <VisitedCity cityID="6">
            <Date>1883-08-26</Date>
            <Visitor>Dora</Visitor>
        </VisitedCity>
        <VisitedCity cityID="3">
            <Date>1907-01-02</Date>
            <Visitor>Nemo</Visitor>
        </VisitedCity>
        <VisitedCity cityID="4">
            <Date>1940-02-08</Date>
            <Visitor>Jimenez</Visitor>
        </VisitedCity>
        <VisitedCity cityID="7">
            <Date>2006-09-11</Date>
            <Visitor>Cook</Visitor>
        </VisitedCity>
        <VisitedCity cityID="2">
            <Date>1886-06-10</Date>
            <Visitor>James T. Kirk</Visitor>
        </VisitedCity>
        <VisitedCity cityID="8">
            <Date>1996-11-10</Date>
            <Visitor>Andree</Visitor>
        </VisitedCity>
    </VisitedCities> </Atlas>
```

The wanted output is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Atlas>
    <Cities>
        <City id="1" worldPart="Africa">
            <Name>Luxor</Name>
            <Founded>-3200</Founded>
            <Location>Egypt</Location>
        </City>
        <City id="2" worldPart="Africa">
            <Name>Tripoli</Name>
            <Founded>-700</Founded>
            <Location>Libya</Location>
        </City>
        <City id="3" worldPart="Americas">
            <Name>Cholula</Name>
            <Founded>-200</Founded>
            <Location>Mexico</Location>
        </City>
        <City id="4" worldPart="Americas">
            <Name>Flores</Name>
            <Founded>-1000</Founded>
            <Location>Guatemala</Location>
        </City>
        <City id="5" worldPart="Europe">
            <Name>Argos</Name>
            <Founded>-5000</Founded>
            <Location>Greece</Location>
        </City>
        <City id="6" worldPart="Europe">
            <Name>Athens</Name>
            <Founded>-4000</Founded>
            <Location>Greece</Location>
        </City>
        <City id="7" worldPart="Asia">
            <Name>Varanasi</Name>
            <Founded>-1800</Founded>
            <Location>India</Location>
        </City>
        <City id="8" worldPart="Asia">
            <Name>Jakarta</Name>
            <Founded>397</Founded>
            <Location>Indonesia</Location>
        </City>
    </Cities>
    <VisitedCities lastUpdate="2018-09-10">
        <VisitedCity cityID="2">
            <Date>1886-06-10</Date>
            <Visitor>James T. Kirk</Visitor>
        </VisitedCity>
        <VisitedCity cityID="6">
            <Date>1883-08-26</Date>
            <Visitor>Dora</Visitor>
        </VisitedCity>
        <VisitedCity cityID="3">
            <Date>1907-01-02</Date>
            <Visitor>Nemo</Visitor>
        </VisitedCity>
        <VisitedCity cityID="4">
            <Date>1940-02-08</Date>
            <Visitor>Jimenez</Visitor>
        </VisitedCity>
        <VisitedCity cityID="8">
            <Date>1996-11-10</Date>
            <Visitor>Andree</Visitor>
        </VisitedCity>
        <VisitedCity cityID="7">
            <Date>2006-09-11</Date>
            <Visitor>Cook</Visitor>
        </VisitedCity>
    </VisitedCities>
</Atlas>
```

As I understand it, the index-of(), used in the [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52254790/3958843) by Martin Honnen, will contain empty sequence values that either cause those cities to be dropped or sorted before all other cities. Is there a way to define a "fallback" value that is used in place of these empty values? Or do I perhaps need to build a complete reference list to avoid this?

Or have I misunderstood index-of() completely? Please help me sort these unfortunate cities! I use XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `index-of` function returns the empty sequence if the item is not found so you could decide to check for that and in that case return the `count($sort-order) + 1`, an compact way in XPath is to do that is

```
<xsl:sort select="(index-of($sort-order, key('city-by-id', @cityID)/@worldPart), count($sort-order) + 1)[1]"/>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaFJ/1

a longer but perhaps easier to graps version would be to use `

```
if (empty(index-of($sort-order, key('city-by-id', @cityID)/@worldPart))) then count($sort-order) + 1 else index-of($sort-order, key('city-by-id', @cityID)/@worldPart)
```

Comment: Thanks'! I like the first version since it avoids duplication of code. I also realized that another way may be to add a primary sort key component that just groups the values into those that are found in the sort-order list and those that aren't.